# Monitor which processes are responsible for incoming/outgoing traffic

Tags: windows, network-monitoring

I need something to give me traffic usage (in real-time) per process. I remember 'Online Armor' did something like this but that app is too bloated for my purposes.

I hope this isn't a dupe – I've seen questions about traffic monitoring (tools like Netlimiter, DU Meter were suggested) but I need something that will give me even more control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Process Explorer

run it as administrative (you have to run it as administrative for the following "processor network" tab to appear)

view..select columns.."process network"   Then click Receive bytes and Send bytes.
Then sort by one of those columns e.g. Receive bytes.
You can scroll right the right hand (window) pane, so you reach those 2 columns for bytes sent/received, and you still see process name as you see in the pic 'cos  process name is in the left hand pane.

It shows a total rather than a rate.

[image: process explorer window with amendments]

Comment: the network doesn't appear

Comment: @user299709 funnily enough I just got your symptom trying it now but I managed to correct it like this. Don't just run process explorer normally, Run As Administrator, then follow the instruction in my post i.e. to go to view..select columns, I see a 'process network' tab and can choose send and receive. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: @barlop that did it! but seems like when i replace task manager, it still requires administrator privileges.

Comment: @user299709 what do you mean when you say "when i replace task manager" ?

Comment: in the menu, theres an option to replace task manager

Comment: @user299709 would help if you stated where in the file menu. it's in options..replace task manager.Even if u could u still have the UAC issue and i'm not sure off hand how2get around that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur9fFsIRzNY  I think he may have disabled UAC completely from windows though,which is generally not recommended by people.He used a batch file to execute process explorer as admin with an 'elevate' command from www.winability.com  then he converted the bat to an exe. with a program  bat to exe from http://www.f2ko.de,  then(after backing up taskmgr.exe) he replaced taskmgr.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19352/discussion-between-barlop-and-user299709).

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Vista/Windows 7:

1. Start Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Escape)
2. Go to the "Performance" tab
3. Click "Resource Monitor" at the bottom of the pane
4. Go to the "Network" tab

[image: Resource Monitor screenshot]

Comment: You should mention that this "Resource Monitor" feature is not an option in XP

Comment: Good point. Done!