# How can I view MB/s used by a process in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

How can I view MB/s used by a process in Windows XP?

I have checked this similar question [How can I get a MByte/s or Mbit/s reading of network activity?](https://superuser.com/questions/647564/how-can-i-get-a-mbyte-s-or-mbit-s-reading-of-network-activity)   but it covers windows 7(resource monitor) or windows vista(resource monitor), and XP has no resource monitor. And it covers perfmon for network adaptors but not for whatever process.

I've checked process explorer  [Monitor which processes are responsible for incoming/outgoing traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/317016/monitor-which-processes-are-responsible-for-incoming-outgoing-traffic)  but as far as I can tell, it only shows total bytes sent/received   It doesn't show the rate, i.e. bytes per unit of time. e.g. MB/s

How can I do it?

**Added**

Network Traffic View  isn't doing it for me. See my comment to that answer, it's not showing process name for some reason.

Comment: I don't have XP to try on but [NetworkTrafficView from nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_traffic_view.html) might work.

Comment: @pun can you state exactly what column it is that you think shows **rate**

Comment: It shows under `maximum data speed`

Comment: @pun and where does it show process name?

Comment: Under `Process Filename`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Network Traffic View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_traffic_view.html) from Nirsoft

[image]

You can customise the units from Options → Speed Unit → kB/s, KiB/s, MB/s etc...

Similarly you can customise columns as well.

Rate shows under **Maximum Data Speed** and Process Name shows under **Process Filename**

Not affiliated :( : *There must be other tools capable of doing this but recomending *Network Traffic View* purely based on my experience with other Nirsoft tools over years*

Comment: i've found his stuff good generally though with this tool i'm getting funny results with it like, no process filename or PID listed   (tested on win7) http://i.imgur.com/cTTi1sL.png

Comment: hmm yeah, I was them too. Checking further some of them show are services like `netbios` but not sure about others.